# Limit grep's output

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I'm trying to make a server manager, but I need to grab the process IDs and Commands of some processes.

For example:

```
 ps ax | grep ./skulltag
 4760 pts/2    Tl     0:02 ./skulltag-server
 4793 pts/2    Tl     0:01 ./skulltag-server
 4956 pts/2    Tl     0:01 ./skulltag-server -port 13000
 4958 pts/2    Tl     0:26 ./skulltag-server -port 13001
```

How would I get it to only return the process, only return the command (./skulltag-server) or both? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to consider using the `--format` option to `ps` to get only the fields you're interested in and in a format that you can easily cut with basic shell tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipe to [awk](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.html) to select which field to output

E.g. `ps ax | grep ./skulltag | awk '{ print $1 }'` will print the first column (pid)

Note that you may also want to look into using the -o option to [ps](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps) to modify its output

Comment: I'm trying to use this in conjunction with a PHP script, however, using $COMMAND = shell_exec("ps ax | grep ./skulltag | awk '{print $5}"); and echo $COMMAND, $COMMAND doesn't return anything. Is there any way I could get it to display the single command on a webpage via php? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, ps --format command | grep ./skulltag did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use awk

```
ps ax | grep ./skulltag | awk '{print $1}'  # Or $5, or $1 and $5
```

This will give you the list of the process ids.

Answer (score 3):

For getting process ids you can also use non-standard but handy [`pgrep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep).

```
ps ax | grep ./skulltag | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Is roughly equivalent to:

```
pgrep skulltag
```

Comment: Great! I wasn't aware of `pgrep`

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the results of `ps ax` using `awk` to extract the columns you want:

```
aix@aix:~/tmp$ ps ax | grep bash
 1906 pts/5    Ss+    0:00 bash
13749 pts/31   Ss     0:00 bash
27315 ?        SN     0:00 /bin/bash /etc/cron.daily/backup
27648 pts/31   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto bash

aix@aix:~/tmp$ ps ax | grep bash | awk '{print $1}'
1906
13749
27315
27652

aix@aix:~/tmp$ ps ax | grep bash | awk '{print $5}'
bash
bash
/bin/bash
grep
```